# How to make dropdown expanded in desktop view but collapsed in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Currently in all screen sizes by default, the dropdown is expanded and for that, I've used $('#id_name').toogleClass('open') for expanding and collapsing. But I need to make dropdown work expanded by default in desktop view but collapsed by default in mobile view.

Please help me with that anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.innerHeight, let  width = window.innerWidth.

```
   if (width <= 768) {
// you code for mobile view
}else{
  // your code for desktop view
}
```

768 == iPhone 10 width

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries in jss

`
//Create a condition that targets
viewports at least 768px wide

constmediaQuery=window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)')

```
function handleTabletChange(e) { 
// Check if the media query is true 
if  (e.matches) { 
// Then toggle the class here
console.log('Media Query Matched!') } 
}
// Register event listener
```

mediaQuery.addListener(handleTabletChange)
// Initial check
handleTabletChange(mediaQuery)
`

Answer (score 0):

```js
   if (width <= 768) {
  $dropdown.slideUp();
}else{
  $dropdown.slidedown();
}
```

it will work for you.